# for loop reading twice before executing

Tags: java, for-loop

Wenever I run this program the for loop always prints out the message inside it 2 times before letting me assign anything to the string inside it, but it increments the `i` variable.

Here is the loop:

```
String rua;

for(int i = 1 ; i < horizontal ; i++ ){
    do{
        System.out.println("Introduza os "+ vertical + " valores da rua " + i);
        rua = stringTest("erro", sc);
    } while(rua.length() != vertical);
}
```

It always prints the message twice, one with `i = 1` and the other with `i = 2`  before letting me assign any sort of text to the string.
I see no reason for this to happen and cant find the bug.

rest of the code as requested

```
public class SeriousLand {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Quantas ruas horizontais? (valor entre 2 e 50)");
    int horizontal = SeriousLand.lerValorNoIntervalo(2, 50, "Pretendo um inteiro entre 2 e 50", sc);
    System.out.println("Quantas ruas verticais? (valor entre 2 e 50)");
    int vertical =SeriousLand.lerValorNoIntervalo(2, 50, "Pretendo um inteiro entre 2 e 50", sc);
    System.out.println("Qual a rua horizontal do ponto P? (valor entre 1 e "+horizontal+")");
    int horiP = SeriousLand.lerValorNoIntervalo(1, horizontal, "Pretendo um inteiro entre 1 e "+ horizontal, sc);
    System.out.println("Qual a rua vertical do ponto P? (valor entre 1 e " + vertical + ")");
    int veriP =SeriousLand.lerValorNoIntervalo(1, vertical, "Pretendo um inteiro entre 1 e " + vertical, sc);

            String rua;

            for(int i = 1 ; i < horizontal ; i++ ){
                do{
        System.out.println("Introduza os "+ vertical + " valores da rua " + i);
        rua = stringTest("erro", sc);

                }
                while(rua.length() != vertical);

                }        
            //linha++;



    /*do {
        for (int i = 1; i <= horizontal; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduza os "+ vertical + " valores da rua " + i);
            val = true;
            for (int j = 1; j <= vertical; j++) {
                int valor = sc.nextInt();
                if (valor != '-' || valor != '.') {
                    SeriousLand.imprimeErro(vertical, i);
                    val = false;
                }
            }
            linha++;
        } 
    }while (linha <= horizontal);



    */
    }

 static String lerSimbolo ( String errMess, Scanner sc ) {
    boolean erro = true;
    String simbolo = "";
    do {
        if ( sc.hasNextLine () ) {
        simbolo = sc.nextLine ();  // consome a String
        erro = false;
        }   
        else {
        sc.next ();      // consome o que lah esteja
        System.out.println ( errMess );
        }               
    } while ( erro );

    return simbolo;

}



/**
 * Ler numero inteiro no canal de leitura
 * @param errMess - mensagem a escrever no System.out caso o valor 
 *              acessivel no canal de leitura nao seja um inteiro
 * @param sc - canal de leitura
 * @return valor inteiro
 * @requires errMess != null && sc != null
 */
static int lerInteiro ( String errMess, Scanner sc ) {
    int valor = 0;
    boolean erro = true;
    do {
        if ( sc.hasNextInt () ) {
        valor = sc.nextInt ();  // consome o inteiro
        erro = false;
        }   
        else {
        sc.next ();      // consome o que lah esteja
        System.out.println ( errMess );
        }               
    } while ( erro );

    return valor;

} 


/**
 * Ler numero inteiro no canal de leitura que esta num dado intervalo
 * @param infLim   Limite inferior do intervalo
 * @param supLim  Limite superior do intervalo
 * @param errMess  Mensagem de  erro a apresentar no System.out
 * @param sc  Canal de leitura
 * @return um valor entre infLim e supLim
 * @requires sc != null && infLim <= supLim && errMess != null
 */
static int lerValorNoIntervalo(int infLim, int supLim, 
                                     String errMess, Scanner sc) {
    int valor = 0;
    boolean erro;
    do {
        valor = lerInteiro ( errMess, sc );
        erro = valor < infLim || valor > supLim;
        if ( erro )
           System.out.println ( errMess );
    } while ( erro );

    return valor;
}

public static int lerValorDaLinha(String rua, int coluna, Scanner sc,String erroMess){
    int conta = rua.length() + 1;
    boolean erro;
    do {
        conta = coluna;
        erro = conta < coluna || conta > coluna;
        if ( erro )
           System.out.println ( erroMess );
    } while ( erro );
    return conta;


}

public static void imprimeErro(int vertical,int linha) {

    System.out.println("Erro nos valores introduzidos! Tente de novo");     
    System.out.println("Introduza os "+ vertical + " valores da rua " + linha + " : ");

    }
    public static String stringTest (String errMess, Scanner sc){
        String teste = sc.nextLine();
        boolean erro = false;



        do {
            teste.replaceAll("-","");
            teste.replaceAll(".","");



            if(teste.length() == 0)
                erro = true;
            else
                System.out.println(errMess);
        }
        while(erro = false);


        return teste;

    }
```

}

Comment: Provide complete code.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is probably in your input method.

Comment: What does stringTest() do, what is "vertical", "horizontal", and "sc"?

Comment: string test recieves a user imput string simply , and to verify that it is only composed of "-" and "." i make them null and then check if the string size is null.
vertical is the number of vertical collums
horizontal is the number of horizontal collums
sc is the name of my scanner

Comment: there were some posts about not using a do while because it runs twice , even without the do while , either being just a for or a for with a while inside , they both run 2 times before leting me anything , i have just checked it.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to check if the String is only filled with char '-' or '.' and you didn't refer but you also need o check if the length is correct.
to do this you will have to create methods to verify that: (incompleed code)

```
String rua = verificaTamanhoSimbolos(sc, vertical);

verificaTamanhoSimbolos(Scanner sc, int vertical) {
boolean erro = true;
do{
erro = true;
System.out.println("Introduza os "+ vertical + " valores da rua " + i);
String linha = sc.nextLine();
if(verificaTamanho(linha, verticais)) erro = false;
else System.out.println("Tamanho errado");
if(verificaSimbolos(linha)) erro = false;
else System.out.println("Simbolo errado");
}while(erro);

verificaTamanho(String linha, int verticais) {
if(linha.length() == verticais) return true;
else return false
}

verificaSimbolos(String linha) {
boolean erro = true;
for (int c = 0; c < linha.length(), c++) {
if (linha.charAt(c) != '-' && linha.charAt(c) != '.') erro = false;
}
return erro;
}
```